# Rails model that has both 'has_one' and 'has_many' but with some constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am mapping 2 models:

```
User
Account

class Account 
  has_many :users


class User
  has_one :account
```

The user table as the account_id in it.

Now on the Account model I want to create a 'primary user' which an account only has 1 off.
The user table has a boolean flag :is_primary, how can I create a has_one on the account side for a user who has the is_primary and account_id mapped.

So the SQL would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM users where account_id=123 and is_primary = 1
```

So I want:

A user has an account.
An account has many users, and has a single primary user also.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Approach 1 - Add a new association**

Add an `has_one` association with a `where` lambda. This allows you to work within your current schema.

```
class Account 
  has_many :users
  has_one  :primary_user, -> { where(is_primary: true) }, :class_name=> "User"
end
```

Now:

```
account.users #returns all users associated with the account
account.primary_user #returns the primary user associated with the account
# creates a user with is_primary set to true
account.build_primary_user(name: 'foo bar', email: 'bar@foo.com')
```

**Approach 2 - Add an association method**

```
class Account 
  has_many :users do
    def primary
      where(:is_primary => true).first
    end
  end
end
```

Now:

```
account.users.primary # returns the primary account
```

Comment: would appreciated your comments on this, as it is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365068/rails-model-that-has-both-has-one-and-has-many-but-with-some-contraints

Comment: Nice and clean approach. Would you mind explaining how to update the primary_user in a account#update form with a (collection_)select of all users, using approach 1 ? Thank you

Comment: @Patient55 Have you tried using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Answer (score 6):

It would probably be simpler to add a primary_user_id field to Account, and add a 'has_one' association for the primary_user:

```
class Account
  has_many :users
  has_one :primary_user, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  has_one :account
end
```

If you must use the existing schema (with the :is_primary boolean flag), you can add a scope like this:

```
class User
  has_one :account
  scope :primary, where(:is_primary => true)
end
```

and then chain the scope to the users lookup:

```
account = Account.find(1)
primary_user = account.users.primary.first
```

Comment: +1 for first approach. Though `account.users.primary` more expressive than `account.users.primary.first`

Comment: Very true as the naming convention doesn't flow well.  But this is easily rectified by calling the scope `primaries`, and making a class method defined as `def self.primary; primaries.first; end`.  Now you can use the general scope `primaries`, or the method `primary` to refer to a single record (where only 1 is expected)

Comment: -1 Account has no business storing user information. The cleanest approach is to introduce a AccountPrimaryUser tie model, and a uniqueness validation on `account_primary_users.account_id` column will make sure there is ever only one primary user.