# Rails model that includes both a has_many and has_one relationship, relating two models that have a has_many to has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, has-one, has-one-through

This is a slight extension of this question: [Rails model that has both 'has_one' and 'has_many' but with some contraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365068/rails-model-that-has-both-has-one-and-has-many-but-with-some-contraints)

Here, I am trying to relate two models that each has_many of the other -> I have an in between model which stores the foreign keys, allowing for a "through" relationship. Specifically, I'm trying to relate matchups and teams, and I'd like for each team to "has_one :current_matchup"

Here are the relevant excerpts from my models:

Team:

```
has_many :matchup_teams
has_many :matchups, through: :matchup_teams
```

Matchup:

```
has_many :matchup_teams
has_many :teams, through: :matchup_teams
```

MatchupTeam:

```
belongs_to :matchup
belongs_to :team
```

How can I do this?
Here is my current attempt, which causes an error:

Model Team:

```
has_one  :current_matchup_team, -> { where(is_current: true) }, :class_name=> "MatchupTeam"
has_one :current_matchup, through: :current_matchup_team, :class_name=>"Matchup"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better aproach if you use a method instead of an association to retrieve the current_matchup:

Model: **Team**

```
def current_matchup
    matchups. where(is_current: true) 
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'm happy to do that - can I use that method in an eager_load statement? For example, user.teams.includes(:current_matchup), or something like that?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it has to be a model relationship.

Comment: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "current_matchup" or :current_matchup in model LeaguesAndTeams::MatchupTeam. Try 'has_many :current_matchup, :through => :current_matchup_team, :source => <name>'. Is it one of matchup or team?

Comment: I removed the namespaces in my question above for brevity